# ICD3err0045 - PIC16F819 Programming

Tags: pic, programming, error

After posting: [Programming/Debugging with ICD3 and PIC16F819-I/P](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/53064/programming-debugging-with-icd3-and-pic16f819-i-p)

I'm still getting the MPLAB error:
ICD3Err0045 - You must connect a target device to use MPLAB ICD 3

My Setup (pinout and wireup):
[image: PIC16F819 Pinout and Current Configuration]

MPLAB Screen (You may need to zoom in a bit):
[image]

I did notice that under Programmer > Settings > Status:

[image]

- Target Vdd seems wrong (0.02 persist even after clicking 'refresh').
- "Allow ICD 3 to select memories and ranges" is set
- "Power target circuit from MPLAB ICD3" is unchecked.
- <del>Voltage between PIC pins 5 and 14 is 5.14, but once I try to connect to ICD3 and 
  click "Reconnect" this voltage drops to 3.4</del>
- My voltage supply is an AC to DC adapter from a wireless mic receiver (SHURE PS21US,
  output 12V, 400 mah) put through a <del>voltage divider</del> [L7805CV](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheet/stmicroelectronics/2143.pdf) to give me   5.08 volts.
- The datasheet for the PIC16F819 can be found [here](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/103284/MICROCHIP/PIC16F819.html).

EDIT: I added a 5V voltage regulator, and a .01uF cap across Vdd and GND (before it even goes to the regulator), and a 2.6k resistor in series with !MCLR. Still getting the same error (Programmer status remains unchanged even after refresh - it's like ICD3 isn't grounded...just guessing though).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should have a pullup on MCLR. Did you try programming with external power provided from your 5V supply (disconnecting power from ICD3?)

Comment: Also, you absolutely need a ~0.1 uF capacitor between the Vdd and Vss pins for decoupling. If you don't have any capacitors across your power rails, you will almost definitely have weird issues.

Comment: Ah, so my 0.01 uF isn't going to cut it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check your RJ11 connector to ensure that everything was wired up correctly?

E.G.

From the ICD3 Quick Start Poster:
[image: icd3poster]

*what that means* is that  *from* the ICD3, that is:
[image: icd3]

PGM will be on the far left, Vpp will be on the far right...

Note that the numbers on your RJ11 connector will be upside down, AND the mapping will be *exactly* like "Target Connection Pinout" on the rest of the poster!
[image: TargetDeviceICD3Poster]

After all that, to find out my connector was just upside down! All I had to do was re-wire the lines from the connector to the breadboard and boom: MPLAB detected everything! Now I'm off to the software side! 
[image: RJ11]

Thanks again to all who helped out!!

Comment: Did I feel kind of silly? Yes. Oh well, sometimes it pays to take a step back, and start looking at the forest :)

Answer (score 4):

That error indicates that the target device isn't powered. Check that the supply to the Vdd pin is present.

The use of a voltage divider is probably the cause of the problem. Use a proper regulator.

The Vdd pin should be decoupled.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion! I'll (hopefully) be able to test this soon. I think you're right about the voltage divider.

Comment: Supply voltage is good, swapped divider for a regulator, decoupled Vdd...any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you wanted to supply the MCU with a voltage divider of maybe 1K and 1K2. If so, probably your circuit has no power after drawing 10 mA or else it's destroyed and shorted with a voltage over 7V5. Use a 78L05 or similar, do things well.

Comment: I'll check my IC's to see if I have a regulator lying around. Thank you!

Comment: Found one!! See edits.